# Android - Creating and managing activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created TWO screens which i will paste the code below.

```
`FirstScreen:` i have a button and when tap/click it will go to `SecondScreen`
`SecondScreen:` i have a button and when tap/click it will go to `FirstScreen`
```

//code://

```
public class FirstScreen extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPressMe);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, SecondScreen.class));
            }
        }); 
    } 
}


public class SecondScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoToThirdScreen);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, SecondScreen.class));
                //HOW DO I GOT TO FIRST SCREEN????
            }
        }); 
    } 
}
```

if there is a better of way of doing please let me know. - Thanks.

Comment: I guess calling finish on this activity will take you back to First screen (unless you want to send some values to first screen from here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go **back** to the first activity, you just need to finish the second one, not create new instance of the first activity, this is done like that:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
```

To start the second activity from the first one, you should do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class));
```

Comment: i get this error when i try the above code (second line)

`Description Resource Path Location Type
No enclosing instance of the type Main is accessible in scope SecondScreen.java /LearnActivities/src/net/issoa/Activities line 26 Java Problem
`

Comment: Please make sure you replace `Main.this` with `FirstActivity.this` as in my answer.

Comment: here is i have in my code:

`startActivity(new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class));` FirstScreen.java file i have and what is FirstActivity coming from?

Comment: My mistake, I meant `FirstScreen.this`

Comment: yes i have firstscreen.this, as i have in the above post but still get the same error which i have posted

Comment: If you omitted any `Main` from your code, you should not get this error, try clean and rebuild the project, if you still get an error (maybe a different one) post it here.

Comment: okay i have created a new proj, with two files in it, Main.java and FirstScreen.java so if i am on FirstScreen and go back to the Main screen, here is what i have in my code `startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, FirstScreen.class));` still get the same error :(

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type Main is accessible in scope

Comment: Why do you have `Main.this` ? it should be `FirstScreen.this`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could call `finish()` instead of starting a new activity via intent. `onDestroy()` is called after `finish()`  closing the activity.

If you try to go back via intent you would also need the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag set via `setFlags()` or you would end up with a lot activities in the back stack if you kept swapping between them.

You should really use the built in back button unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: thanks for the inside, do you have a sample where i can learn? 1+

Comment: The android docs are a good place to start try these http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: i have been looking and reading as i go.... do you have any samples to play with?

Answer (score 1):

In the second class,use the function finish().

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick() for the button on the second screen, put just one line:

Finish();